# Filter by greater than for a groupby count syntax in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a syntax to groupby the airlines data as per the Air_time.

```
largest_airlines = flight_data.groupby(['AIRLINE'])['AIR_TIME'].count()
print (len(largest_airlines))
largest_airlines
```

The output is:

```
AIRLINE
AA     8720
AS      768
B6      540
DL    10539
EV     5697
F9     1305
HA      111
MQ     3314
NK     1486
OO     6425
UA     7680
US     1593
VX      986
WN     8310
Name: AIR_TIME, dtype: int64
```

I want to filter the data greater than 2500. Can anyone help me in the syntax for the same.

Comment: pandas? numpy? [mcve]?

Comment: Hey @Rush, and welcome to SO! I'm assuming you want to print only the data greater than 2500. To do this, you could create a simple `for` loop to loop through `largest_airlines`, use an `if` statement to check if each item's data is greater than 2500, and do whatever manipulation you need within the `if` which would be nested within your loop. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what method you want to use for it.

In pandas, for example, you could use something like this:

`greater_than_2500_df = largest_airlines.loc[largest_airlines['Air_Time'] < 2500]`

But it would help to see something you've tried first.